# CSS ::selection not working in Google Chrome

Tags: css, html

I have this code which works fine in internet explorer and Mozilla Firefox but it fails on Google Chrome, this is the basic CSS `::selection` selector.
Attached is an illustration of the problem:

**Desired result: (IE, Firefox)**
[image]

**What's wrong: (Chrome)**
[image]

This only happens in Google Chrome, I am attaching the code I've tried here:

```css
::-moz-selection {
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
}
::selection  {
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
}
::-webkit-selection {
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Hello World!</li>
  <li>What's up?</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`::-webkit-selection` doesn't seem to fix the issue, but there is another workaround for it:

```css
::-moz-selection {
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
}
::selection {
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
}
ol {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}
ol span {
  -webkit-user-select: all;
  -moz-user-select: all;
  -ms-user-select: all;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li><span>Hello World!</span></li>
  <li><span>What's up?</span></li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add `::-webkit-selection`

Comment: @odedta Try `#FFA500` instead of `orange`

Answer (score 1):

Still wasn't working but this worked for me...

```
    * {
     -webkit-user-select: text;
     -moz-user-select: text;
     -ms-user-select: text; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still having this issue, check to see you don't have any unspecified `:first-letter`

Answer (score 0):

For me it seemed like `::-moz-selection` was the issue.

When removing it the selection appeared as I wanted in Chrome.